# Calling FirstOrDefault multiple times in LINQ to set object properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query like so:

```
var Item = (from s in contextD.Items where s.Id == Id select s).ToList();
```

Further down the Item object properties are set like so:

```
Item.FirstOrDefault().Qty = qtyToUpdate;
Item.FirstOrDefault().TotalPrice = UItem.FirstOrDefault().Qty *  UItem.FirstOrDefault().Price;
 ...
```

My question is, will calling FirstOrDefault always loop through the result set returned by the query?

Shouldn't a single call be made and put in an object like so:

```
MyObject objMyObject = new MyObject;
objMyObject = Item.FirstOrDefault();
```

and then go about setting objMyObject properties.

The first part using FirstOrDefault is actually in the production, I am trying to find out if that's the right way.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will calling FirstOrDefault always loop through the result set
>   returned by the query?

`FirstOrDefault()` never loops through *all* result set - it either returns first item, or default if set is empty. Also in this particular case even enumerator will not be created - thus you are calling `FirstOrDefault()` on variable of `List<T>` type, simply item at index `0` will be returned (if list is not empty). If you will investigate `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()` implementation:

```
IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
if (list != null)
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        return list[0];
    }
}
```

But this will be invoked each time you are calling `FirstOrDefault()`.

Also you are missing 'default' case. If you are chaining methods like in your first sample, you can get `NullReferenceException` if list is empty. So, make sure something was returned by query:

```
var item = Item.FirstOrDefault();
if (item == null)
    return; // or throw

item.Qty = qtyToUpdate;
var uitem = UItem.FirstOrDefault();
if (uitem == null)
    return; // or throw

item.TotalPrice = uitem.Qty * uitem.Price;
```

One more note - you have little difference in performance if you are performing `FirstOrDefault()` on in-memory collection. But difference will be **huge** if you will perform it without saving query results into list. In that case *each* `FirstOrDefault()` call will cause *new database query*.

Comment: So does putting the the first into an object yield any benefits other than avoiding the call many times?

Comment: @Codehelp you will pay with one more reference on stack, but you will save method call. BTW don't forget to check 'default' case. FirstOrDefault() can return null and you will get an NullReferenceException